# Can company A verify offer pay with company B?

Tags: salary, job-offer, employment

I have 2 offers, one from company A and one from company B. I accepted company B's offer due to the it being a lot better than company A. During the interview process, I told company B about the pay that company A is offering and they went above that.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Can company B call company A to verify that I did indeed get an offer letter?
2. Can company B call company A to verify if what I said was true about the pay that was being offered to me?

Comment: Companies do not generally share information about hiring decisions or compensation.  Some companies will provide "employment verification" for reference purposes but that rarely goes beyond "so-and-so was employed here from XXXX until XXXX".  They may add "and held the position of YYYY".  They don't give salary figures or reasons about why that person is no longer employed there.

Comment: Where are you located? In many countries, sharing this information without consent from you would be illegal.

Answer (score 5):

They can ask anything they like.

The probability is that they won't. Unless it's on a personal level there is no reason CompanyB would give out this information.

But on a personal network level anything can happen. I went to an interview once and before my interview had even started my current employer had been informed I was in the waiting room by a staff member who recognised me.

Comment: Spot on. Officially - There is next to no chance this would happen company to company. But as said it's a small world, especially in some industries. People talk, but very unlikely to be about salary. The people in those conversations will more than likely be professional and respectful.

Answer (score 3):

They certainly can.  They won’t though, because company A will tell them “none of your business.”

Comment: And if the two HR people know each other?

Comment: @SolarMike: they still won't since most companies consider offer data confidential.

Comment: @Hilmar we do not know what they would do, but they might.  However, it is highly likely that this would be illegal collusion, but companies have broken the law before.  I think it unlikely that they would share this data.

Comment: If a HR person at A knows an HR person at B, then telling their mate about salaries or offered salaries at A would hurt company A, and if found out, could have very bad consequences for that HR person.

Comment: @SolarMike I still fail to see how this would have any negative consequences for the OP... Even if the HR person knows the OP is lying through private contacts, it is the HR person, and not the OP, who would face consequences if that were “brought to the office”.

Comment: Maybe they know each other, maybe they’re married, maybe they hire ninjas to steal the information… does any of that whataboutism help the OP?

Comment: Even if two HR people know each other, how likely do you think it will be they'll have coffee together, and compare to which people they made offers this week?

Answer (score 0):

They won't; they already know you were probably inflating the number a bit to help the negotiation along.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on country and state. EU, I am sure this would run afoul of GDPR.
US, California has strong laws requiring this information remain confidential.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading too much into this.

Company A offers $xxx. You tell company B how much company A is offering.

**Regardless of the ethics of you sharing that information, one of the following will happen;**

Company B will decide that they can offer $xxx + $x. You take the higher offer.

Company B will decide that they cannot match company A's offer. They offer only $xxx.

Company B will decide that they cannot match company A's offer, and withdraw from the negotiation.

It all depends on the budget company B have for the role, and if they think you're worth it. Even if it was legally possible, company B is never going to check with company A that you have been given an offer.